# How to enable Multiple Node Selections?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am pretty new to Cytoscape.js, however I am not sure how to enable the users ability to left click + command key to select multiple nodes? I do have the initialization option set for boxSelectionEnabled: true (http://js.cytoscape.org/#init-opts/boxSelectionEnabled)

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: My Cytoscape.js layout with one node selected]

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a modifier key (control, alt, command, or shift) is down, you can click to toggle a node's selection state or you can click and drag to perform additive box selection.